# Criando campo dateTime com laravel collective

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-collective

Estou criando um campo utilizando o `Laravel Collective` porém estou tendo problemas com o campo date, primeiramente não estou conseguindo criar o campo DATATIME e outro problema é que ele está vindo o formado do banco, como posso fazer para solucionar estes dois problemas ?

```
{!! Form::date('Visivel_Ini', \Carbon\Carbon::now(), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método é `datetime`:

```
Form::datetime('visivel_Ini', \Carbon\Carbon::now(), ['class'=>'form-control'])
```

Se preferir a data no formato brasileiro:

```
Form::input('text', 'visivel_Ini', \Carbon\Carbon::create()->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'), ['class'=>'form-control'])
```

Comment: Quando coloco este \Carbon\Carbon::now() ele me retorna apenas a data, como fazer para retornar tbem a hora ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues o Carbon::now() vai retorna na verdade uma formato assim: `2016-06-24 15:18:34` igual especificado na doc api http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/. Você precisa exatamente do que?

Comment: Preciso setar no campo a data e hora de hoje

Comment: Fiz a edição...